# Comparison of areas of circular segments (Spivak , ch. 8 ex. 11b)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

I have been working on the following exercise from Spivak book and have got stuck in the following part:
“Suppose $P$ is a regular polygon inscribed in a circle. If $P’$ is the inscribed regular polygon with twice as many sides, show that the difference between the area of the circle and $P’$ is less than half the difference between the area of the circle and $P$.
I have come up with the following formulas for the areas of $P$ and $P’$:
Let $n$ be the number of sides of the regular polygon $P$ and $l$ be te respective length of them. Then, $A(P) = 0.5\times(nlc)$ and $A(P’) = 0.5\times(nlR)$, where $R$ is the radius of the circle and $c=\sqrt{R^2 - \frac{l^2}{4}}.$
I have tried to work from here towards the proof of the inequality asked to but haven’t been able to prove it through this approach.
Update:
Looking at a picture, I have noticed that the area of P’ , A(P’) = n * A(P)/n + 0.5*n*A(R) = A(P) +n*A(R) where R is a rectangle section that remains to add for each 2 sides of P’ apart from the bigger part formed by a single triangle of P.
From here, knowing also from picture that the area of the circle, A(C) < A(P) + n*A(R) , so we have that A(C) - A(P’) < 0.5(A(C) - A(P)) iff 2A(C) - 2A(P’) < A(C) -A(P) iff 2A(C) - 2A(P)+ A(P) -nA(R) < A(C) iff A(C) < A(P) +nA(R) which we know it’s true as observed before.
Note: Please , provide alternative solutions or correction on my current answer without using any trigonometry. For context, this exercise is on the least upper bound chapter, having gone through topics such as limits, continuity , three hard theorems ,axioms and properties of the real numbers.

[image]

Comment: I have come up with another approach which focuses less on the area formulas explicitly but rather in the relations of A(P’) and A(P) based on the picture on the book. I have deduced that A(P’) = A(P) + nA(R) where R is the rectangle leftover next to every two sides of P’. Hence we have that A(C) - A(P’) < 0.5*(A(C) - A(P)) by later manipulations

Comment: Could you give the title of the book by Spivak ?

Comment: Which "Spivak book"?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be informative about the content of your question. Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the Spivak book is Calculus edition 3

Comment: Update my answer with an analytical proof rather than geometric proof. See if its useful. Classical problem !

Comment: @Balajisb I see that your answer makes sense . However , this exercise is intended to be solved without needing to use any trigonometry since so far on the book, those functions have not been analysed.

Comment: @Balajisb Neither derivatives were even introduced so far for this exercise

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, one can assume that the circle is the unit circle.

For a regular polygon with $n$ sides, let us reason on the circular sector with angle $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ as represented in the following picture :

[image]

Knowing that the area of a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) subtended by angle $\theta$ in a circle with radius $R$ is

$$\frac{R^2}{2}(\theta-\sin \theta),$$

we have to show that :

$$2 \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{n}-\sin \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}_{\text{area of red circ. segment}} \ \le \ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}-\sin \frac{2\pi}{n} \right)\tag{1}$$

Let $x:=\frac{\pi}{n}$. (1) becomes :

$$x-2 \sin x +\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x \le 0 \tag{2}$$

In fact, inequality (2) is valid for all $x, \ 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

(2) can be written under the following form placing in evidence the so-called function "cardinal sine" :

$$\forall x \in (0, \pi/2), \ \ x-\sin x(2-\cos x) \le 0 \ \iff $$

$$\frac{1}{2-\cos(x)} \le \underbrace{\frac{\sin x}{x}}_{\text{card. sine}}\tag{2'}$$

In order to establish inequality (2'), we are going to use a consequence of the **Cusa-Huygens inequality** that can be found for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01688.pdf) :

$$\forall x \in (0,\pi/2), \ \ \left(\frac{2+ \cos(x)}{3}\right)^{\alpha} \le \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \ \text{with} \ \alpha \approx 1.11$$

from which we deduce that "a fortiori" :

$$\forall x \in (0,\pi/2), \ \ \left(\frac{2+ \cos(x)}{3}\right)^{3/2} \le \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

In order to prove (2'), it is sufficient to establish that :

$$\forall x \in (0,\pi/2), \ \  \frac{1}{2-\cos(x)} \le \left(\frac{2+ \cos(x)}{3}\right)^{3/2} $$

As this inequality deals with positive numbers, it is equivalent to the same type of inequality where the LHS and RHS are taken at the power $2$, which amounts to prove that :

$$\forall x \in (0,\pi/2), \ \ (2-\cos(x))^2(2+\cos(x))^3 \ge 9\tag{3}$$

(with equality when $x=(2 k+1)\pi$).

Inequality (3) is equivalent to :

$$\underbrace{(4-\cos(x)^2)^2}_{ \ge \ 9}\underbrace{(2+\cos(x))}_{\ge \ 1} \ge 9$$

which is evidently true, besides without any domain restriction...

(with equality if and only if $x=(2 k+1)\pi$).

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the Spivak book, but here is an approach without numbers.

Let $IG$ be the side of an $n$-gon and $IH$ the side of a $2n$-gon in the same circle. The circular segment on $IG$ is thus $\frac{1}{n}$th of the difference between the circle's area and that of the $n$-gon. And twice the segment on $IH$ is $\frac{1}{n}$th of the difference between the circle's area and that of the $2n$-gon. We want to show that segment areas$$2IUH<\frac{1}{2}IHG$$
[image: n-gon/2n-gon]

Draw tangents at $H$ and $I$, make $IZ=HW$, join $ZH$, and drop perpendicular $HT$.

Since in rhombus $IZHW$, $\angle HIW=\angle HGI=\angle GIH$, then $WIH$, $ZIH$ are congruent isosceles triangles, and $ZI$, $ZH$ are tangents to segment$$IVH=IUH$$and both segments together are contained within $HTIU$, which is half the segment on $IG$.

Therefore,$$2IUH<\frac{1}{2}IHG$$

Answer (score 1):

Length $\ell$ of a side of regular n-polygon: wlog: $$\ell^2 
 = d(r(\cos(0),\sin(0)),r(\cos(2\pi/n),\sin(2\pi/n)))^2 = r^2(1-\cos(2\pi/n))^2 + r^2 \sin(2\pi/n)^2 = r^2 \times 2(1-\cos(2\pi/n)) = r^2 \times 4 \times \sin^2(\pi/n).$$

$$\mathrm{Area\ of\  n -polygon} : n \times \mathrm{ Area \ of \ the \ sector \ triangle }$$
$$\mathrm{Area \ of \ n - polygon }: n \times 1/2 \times r \times 2 \sin(\pi/n) \times  \sqrt{ r^2 - r^2 \sin^2(\pi/n)}$$

$$\mathrm{Area \ of \ n - polygon} : n \times 1/2 \times r^2 \times 2 \sin(\pi/n) \times  \cos(\pi/n)$$

$$\mathrm{Area \ of \ n - polygon }: nr^2 /2 \times \sin(2\pi/n)$$

Area of circle - Area of $2n$-polygon:
$$r^2(\pi- n \times \sin(2\pi/2n))$$

Area of circle - Area of $n$-polygon:
$$r^2(\pi-n /2 \times \sin(2\pi/n))$$

We want prove :
$$r^2(\pi- n \times \sin(2\pi/2n)) \leq 1/2 \times r^2(\pi-n /2 \times \sin(2\pi/n))$$

$$\pi/2 \leq n \times (\sin(\pi/n) -  1/4 \times \sin(2\pi/n))$$

Geometrically, RHS is the area of a $n$ different residual triangles and hence reduces as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and is equal to (Same as what we have derived)

$$n \times 0.5 \times  sin(\pi/n) +  n \times 0.5 \times (1-cos(\pi/n)) \times  sin(\pi/n))$$. Hence,

The first term is half the area of 2n-polygon and second term is the area of a residual triangle. So as $n$ increases first term will increase and second term will decrease. If we show the derivative of first term is smaller then derivative of second term then it shows as $n$ increases, the RHS decreases.

But assuming as $n \rightarrow \infty$, RHS decreases, we have,

$$\pi/2 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \times (\sin(\pi/n) -  1/4 \times \sin(2\pi/n))$$

Using $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \times \sin(\pi/x) = \pi$,

we see that,
$$\pi/2 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \times (\sin(\pi/n) -  1/4 \times \sin(2\pi/n)) = \pi/2$$

Partial Proof that RHS decreases as $n$ increases:

$$f_1(x) = x \times 0.5 \times  sin(\pi/x) $$
$$f_2(x)  = x \times 0.5 \times (1-cos(\pi/x)) \times  sin(\pi/x))$$
$$f_2(x) = f_1(x) \times (1-cos(\pi/x))$$

$$f_1'(x) = 0.5 \times \left(sin(\pi/x)  - \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) \right)$$

$$f_2'(x) = f_1'(x) \times (1-cos(\pi/x))  - \frac{\pi}{x^2} f_1(x) \times sin(\pi/x)$$

Need to show $$-f_2'(x) \geq f_1'(x)$$

$$ - f_1'(x) \times (1-cos(\pi/x))  + \frac{\pi}{x^2} f_1(x) \times sin(\pi/x) \geq f_1'(x)$$

$$ \frac{\pi}{x^2} f_1(x) \times sin(\pi/x) \geq f_1'(x) \times  (2-cos(\pi/x))$$
Using:
$$f_1'(x) = \frac{f_1(x)}{x} - 0.5 \times \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) $$

$$ \frac{\pi}{x^2} f_1(x) \times sin(\pi/x) \geq \frac{f_1(x)}{x} \times  (2-cos(\pi/x)) - 0.5 \times \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) \times (2-cos(\pi/x)) $$

$$ 0.5 \times \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) \times (2-cos(\pi/x)) \geq \left(\frac{1}{x} \times  (2-cos(\pi/x))  - \frac{\pi}{x^2} \times sin(\pi/x) \right) f_1(x)$$

$$ \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) \times (2-cos(\pi/x))  \geq \left((2-cos(\pi/x)) \times sin(\pi/x) - \frac{\pi}{x} \times sin^2(\pi/x) \right) $$

$$ \frac{\pi}{x} \times sin^2(\pi/x) + \frac{\pi}{x} \times cos(\pi/x) \times (2-cos(\pi/x))  \geq \left((2-cos(\pi/x)) \times sin(\pi/x) \right) $$

$$ 2 \times \frac{\pi}{x} \times (sin^2(\pi/x) + cos(\pi/x)  -1/2)  \geq \left(sin(\pi/x) + 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x) \times sin(\pi/x) \right) $$

$$ 2 \times \frac{\pi}{x} \times (sin^2(\pi/x) + 1/2- 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x))  \geq \left(sin(\pi/x) + 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x) \times sin(\pi/x) \right) $$

$$ \frac{\pi}{x} \times \left((2 \times sin^2(\pi/x) -1) +  2 \times (1- 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x) \right)  \geq sin(\pi/x) \times \left(1 + 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x) \right) $$

Since $sin(\pi/x) \leq \pi/x$, its enougn to prove:

$$(2 \times sin^2(\pi/x) -1) +  2 \times (1- 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x)  \geq 1 + 2 \times sin^2(\pi/2x)  $$

$$sin^2(\pi/x) \geq  3 \times sin^2(\pi/2x)  $$

$$cos(\pi/2x) \geq  \sqrt{3}/2  $$
which is true for all $x \geq 4$.

Hence completing the proof.

Comment: As we are on the same tracks, please have a look at my "improved" solution using an ill-known lower bound of the cardinal sine function on $(0, \pi/2)$.

Comment: Thanks Jean. Gave you +1.

Answer (score 0):

Define: n>2 to be the number of sides of the polygon, s = length of each side of the polygon and r = radius of the circle. The area of an inscribed polygon is 1/2(nsr). Now, try solving the inequality:
$\pi r^2 - 1/2(2nsr) < 1/2(\pi r^2 - 1/2nsr)$